# Boost::process on Windows - with MinGW?

Tags: c++, qt, boost, mingw-w64

I have a C++17 application using nothing but STL and boost `1.71.0`. The application needs to run on Windows, Linux and BSD. On Windows I use GCC 9.2 provided by MinGW-w64. I use the distribution that comes with MSYS2.

I need to have the ability to create a system process (launching an external application from within my C++ application).

In the past I used `QProcess` of the Qt libraries for this. However, this application doesn't have any Qt dependencies and I'd like to prevent adding Qt dependencies just for this one feature.

Looking for solutions I came across `boost::process`. On first glance this seems like a very suitable alternative to `QProcess`.

I started by creating a minimal application using C++17, cmake and boost:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/process.hpp>

int main() {
    int result = boost::process::system("g++ main.cpp");

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, I ran into compilation errors straight away:

```
====================[ Build | boost_process_test | Debug ]======================
C:\Users\joel\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\193.5233.103\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\Users\joel\Documents\projects\boost_process_test\cmake-build-debug --target boost_process_test -- -j 6
Scanning dependencies of target boost_process_test
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/boost_process_test.dir/main.cpp.obj
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process/detail/windows/handles.hpp:11,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process/detail/used_handles.hpp:17,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process/detail/windows/async_in.hpp:20,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process/async.hpp:49,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process.hpp:23,
                 from C:\Users\joel\Documents\projects\boost_process_test\main.cpp:2:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process/detail/windows/handle_workaround.hpp:208:51: error: expected ')' before '*' token
  208 | typedef ::boost::winapi::NTSTATUS_ (__kernel_entry *nt_system_query_information_p )(
      |                                    ~              ^~
      |                                                   )
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process/detail/windows/handle_workaround.hpp:223:51: error: expected ')' before '*' token
  223 | typedef ::boost::winapi::NTSTATUS_ (__kernel_entry *nt_query_object_p )(
      |                                    ~              ^~
      |                                                   )
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process/detail/windows/handle_workaround.hpp: In function 'boost::winapi::NTSTATUS_ boost::process::detail::windows::workaround::nt_system_query_information(boost::process::detail::windows::workaround::SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS_, void*, boost::winapi::ULONG_, boost::winapi::PULONG_)':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process/detail/windows/handle_workaround.hpp:239:12: error: 'nt_system_query_information_p' does not name a type; did you mean 'nt_system_query_information'?
  239 |     static nt_system_query_information_p f = reinterpret_cast<nt_system_query_information_p>(::boost::winapi::get_proc_address(h, "NtQuerySystemInformation"));
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |            nt_system_query_information
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process/detail/windows/handles.hpp:11,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process/detail/used_handles.hpp:17,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process/detail/windows/async_in.hpp:20,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process/async.hpp:49,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process.hpp:23,
                 from C:\Users\joel\Documents\projects\boost_process_test\main.cpp:2:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process/detail/windows/handle_workaround.hpp:241:14: error: 'f' was not declared in this scope
  241 |     return (*f)(SystemInformationClass, SystemInformation, SystemInformationLength, ReturnLength);
      |              ^
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process/detail/windows/handle_workaround.hpp: In function 'boost::winapi::BOOL_ boost::process::detail::windows::workaround::nt_query_object(boost::winapi::HANDLE_, boost::process::detail::windows::workaround::OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS_, void*, boost::winapi::ULONG_, boost::winapi::PULONG_)':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process/detail/windows/handle_workaround.hpp:253:12: error: 'nt_query_object_p' does not name a type; did you mean 'nt_query_object'?
  253 |     static nt_query_object_p f = reinterpret_cast<nt_query_object_p>(::boost::winapi::get_proc_address(h, "NtQueryObject"));
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |            nt_query_object
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/process/detail/windows/handle_workaround.hpp:255:14: error: 'f' was not declared in this scope
  255 |     return (*f)(Handle, ObjectInformationClass, ObjectInformation, ObjectInformationLength, ReturnLength);
      |              ^
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\boost_process_test.dir\build.make:62: CMakeFiles/boost_process_test.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:75: CMakeFiles/boost_process_test.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/boost_process_test.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: boost_process_test] Error 2
```

Here is my corresponding `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(boost_process_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(Boost 1.71.0 REQUIRED)

add_executable(boost_process_test main.cpp)
```

I consulted the boost.process documentation to figure out what kind of dependencies & compatibilities there are. Unfortunately, I couldn't find much info on this.

Before I start getting too deep into actually debugging this - Does somebody know whether `boost.process` as of version `1.71.0` actually runs on Windows and if so - whether it works with GCC / MinGW and not just MSVC? And if MinGW/GCC is supported - does it rely on posix or win32api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

I've come across [this github issue](https://github.com/boostorg/process/issues/96) on the `boost::process` repository where the OP mentions the same issue. It appears to be a MinGW issue. A workaround was presented in the issue which involves defining the `__kernel_entry` pre-processor symbol before including the `boost/process.hpp` header.

Applying this to my code looks like this:

```
// Workaround for a boost/mingw bug.
// This must occur before the inclusion of the boost/process.hpp header.
// Taken from https://github.com/boostorg/process/issues/96
#ifndef __kernel_entry
    #define __kernel_entry
#endif

#include <boost/process.hpp>

int main() {
    int result = boost::process::system("g++ main.cpp");

    return 0;
}
```

This made the compilation error(s) go away and resulted in correctly working program binary.

## Further steps

After applying the fix the initial compiler error shown in the question didn't appear anymore. However, the program still didn't compile & link properly as I didn't include the boost libraries correctly.

My `CMakeLists.txt` for the working example looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(boost_process_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(Boost 1.71.0 REQUIRED
    COMPONENTS
        filesystem
        system
)

add_executable(boost_process_test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(boost_process_test
    PRIVATE
        $<$<BOOL:${WIN32}>:ws2_32>
        ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
        ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
)
```

Note the linking towards the `ws2_32` library on Windows platforms.

## Credits

Thank you @ mrjj from the Qt community for pointing me towards the github issue that helped me solving this compilation issue.